# Fill in missing rows when aggregating over multiple fields in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, window-functions, generate-series

I am aggregating sales for a set of products per day using Postgres and need to know not just when sales do happen, but also when they do not for further processing.

```
SELECT 
sd.date, 
COUNT(sd.sale_id) AS sales, 
sd.product

FROM sales_data sd
-- sales per product, per day
GROUP BY sd.product, sd.date
ORDER BY sd.product, sd.date
```

This produces the following:

```
    date    | sales |       product                           
------------+-------+-------------------
 2017-08-17 |  10   | soap
 2017-08-19 |   2   | soap
 2017-08-20 |   5   | soap
 2017-08-17 |   2   | shower gel
 2017-08-21 |   1   | shower gel
```

As you can see - the date ranges per product are not continuous as `sales_data` just didn't contain any info for these products on some days.

What I'm aiming to do is to add a `sales = 0` row for each product that is not sold on any day in a range - for example here, between `2017-08-17` and `2017-08-21` to give something like the the following:

```
    date    | sales |      product                           
------------+-------+-------------------
 2017-08-17 |  10   | soap
 2017-08-18 |   0   | soap
 2017-08-19 |   2   | soap
 2017-08-20 |   5   | soap
 2017-08-21 |   0   | soap
 2017-08-17 |   2   | shower gel
 2017-08-18 |   0   | shower gel
 2017-08-19 |   0   | shower gel
 2017-08-20 |   0   | shower gel
 2017-08-21 |   1   | shower gel
```

In a simpler case where there was only a single product, it seems like the solution would be to use `generate_series()` i.e.:

- create a full range of dates using generate_series
- `LEFT JOIN` the already aggregated sales data onto the date series
- `COALESCE` any `NULL` counts to 0 in the missing rows

The problem I have is that this approach does not seem to work dates repeat in the aggregated data as I'm grouping over not just multiple dates, but multiple products also.

It *feels* like I should be able to do something cunning with window functions here to solve this e.g. joining onto the full date range over partitions defined by the product name - but I can't see a way of actually getting this to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT date, s.product
   FROM  ... -- some way to generate date series
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT product FROM sales_data) s
)
SELECT 
    c.date,
    c.product,
    COUNT(sd.sale_id) AS sales
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN sales_data sd
  ON c.date = sd.date AND c.product= sd.product
GROUP BY c.date, c.product
ORDER BY c.date, c.product;
```

First create Cartesian product of dates and products, then `LEFT JOIN` to actual data and do calculations.

---

Oracle has great feature for this scenarios called **[Partitioned Outer Joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2177515)**:

```
SELECT times.time_id, product, quantity 
FROM inventory  PARTITION BY  (product) 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN times ON (times.time_id = inventory.time_id) 
WHERE times.time_id BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/04/01', 'DD/MM/YY') 
      AND TO_DATE('06/04/01', 'DD/MM/YY') 
ORDER BY  2,1;
```

Comment: Perfect - works exactly as needed, thanks.

Also - that Oracle version does look great indeed <3

Comment: This was VERY helpful for a similar issue I was having.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    date, 
    count(sale_id) as sales, 
    product
from
    sales_data
    right join (
        (
            select d::date as date
            from generate_series (
                (select min(date) from sales_data),
                (select max(date) from sales_data),
                '1 day'
            ) gs (d)
        ) gs
        cross join
        (select distinct product from sales_data) p
    ) cj using (product, date)
group by product, date
order by product, date
```