# Count of Daily Users in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that looks like this

```
users
phone        created
8001234578   1540231160
9001234578   1540220360
1001234578   1540144760
2001234578   1540058360
```

Note that the `created` column is a unix timestamp.

I want to group them by users created on the same day with a count of users, so the above example database should return something like this.

```
[
  {day: '10/22/2018', count: 2},
  {day: '10/21/2018', count: 1},
  {day: '10/20/2018', count: 1},
]
```

I tried learning about the to_char command but I couldn't figure it out, this is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
  to_char(created, 'Day') as day,
COUNT(*) as count
FROM users
WHERE created >= ${startDate} AND created <= ${endDate}
GROUP BY to_char(created, 'Day')
```

It returned this:

```
[{day: ' .ay', count: '4'}]
```

Comment: There is no `date` or `timestamp` column in your `users` table, so how would you know on which day they were created?

Comment: the created column is the timestamp

Comment: 1540231160 is not a valid timestamp value in SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if it's within your control, you should consider using Postgres's built in `TIMESTAMP` data type, instead of storing your dates as UNIX timestamps. This will make your queries much easier.

That being said, if you're stuck with using UNIX timestamps (presumably stored as integers), you'll have to convert them to a `TIMESTAMP` anyways to get what you want. You can use the `TO_TIMESTAMP` to convert from the UNIX timestamp, and use the `DATE_TRUNC` function to just get the date portion:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('day', TO_TIMESTAMP(created)), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', TO_TIMESTAMP(created))
```

Of course, if you're storing the dates as a Postgres TIMESTAMP, it's the same query, but simpler:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('day', created), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', created)
```

Comment: this works great! Any idea how to include days that have a 0 count as part of the results?

Comment: If you need to include days that aren't in your data, you can use something like `generate_series` ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html)) to create the dates you need.

Comment: could you provide an example? I can't figure it out from the documentation

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45738514/9990662) for information on using `generate_series` to "fill in the missing dates". If you're still having issues, you might want to create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can set datetime format, so you got result like this

```
postgres# select to_char(now(), 'DD Mon YYYY');
   to_char   
-------------
 22 Oct 2018
(1 row)
```

In your case query will be like this

```
SELECT 
  to_char(created, 'DD Mon YYYY') as day,
COUNT(*) as count
FROM users
WHERE created >= ${startDate} AND created <= ${endDate}
GROUP BY to_char(created, 'DD Mon YYYY')
```

Here you can find datetime format specification https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', users.created) "day", count(*) as count
FROM users
WHERE created >= ${startDate} AND created <= ${endDate}
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `date_trunc(unknown, double precision) does not exist`

Comment: The `date_trunc` function requires a Postgres `TIMESTAMP`-type value, not a UNIX timestamp type.

Comment: So the column is a double rather than an actual timestamp which means you can't use that function.
you might be able to do 

    date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(users.created)) "day",

Comment: I got it working with this: `date_trunc('day', to_timestamp(users.created)) "day",` Now I just need to figureout how to get it into the right timezone

Comment: It should be UTC, so you can just convert from there

Comment: How would I convert it? The to_timestamp already groups it as UTC